# Creating an empty file in a directory

Tags: java, file, object, input, output

I am a new java student currently working on File I/O. My professor has asked us to create a very simple "DC universe" game using interfaces and classes and has asked us in the current lab I am working on, to create an instance of an object and then save the file to a directory in our C drive. My problem, is that even after all my constant 2 hours of digging through past topics I still cannot find a proper explanation as to how I create a directory and THEN create a file and write to a file in that directory because it appears whenever I run my code to not be able to do both tasks simultaneously. The code below also contains an error at the "Print Writer" line and asks to add a throw clause for "file not found exception"

Any and all help is vastly appreciated

```
package runtime;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;  
import model.hero.*;

public class Gameplay {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    File x = new File("C://prog24178//dcheroes.dat"); 

        if(!x.exists()){
            x.mkdir(); 
        }

    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(x); 
    // 1. Create a save file called dcheroes.dat in {$root}\prog24178
    // 2. Create a hero
    // 3. Save hero to file

}
```

}

Comment: You might like to write \\ instead of `//`.  Otherwise bad things may happen :D

Answer (score 1):

Two errors I see:

- `x.mkdir()` will try to create `C:\prog24178\dcheroes.dat` as a directory. Use `x.getParent().mkdir()` to create `C:\prog24178`.
- the `PrintWriter` error is Java complaining about you not catching a *potential* error. Your code is fine, it's just Java being demanding. Surround your code with a `try { ... } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) { ... }` block. Every function call that could potentionally throw an `Exception` needs to have that exception caught, or the containing function needs to be marked to also be a potential source of the exception (and you can't do the latter on `main`).